# If professionals mount my TV, is it their job to hide the wires?

Tags: mounting

Yesterday I paid $250 to have my TV mounted by professionals contracted by the big name electronics store where I bought the TV. I was at home while they did the work, gave them the thumbs up when I saw the TV was level and the bracket firmly in place. Satisfied, I showed them the door.

Then my mother saw the job. She immediately noticed the exposed cords, as mothers are prone to do. And she said, "It's OK Sam, you just didn't know what you were doing."

While it's true, I don't know anything at all about TV mounting standards, I'm not sure that it was the professionals' job to hide the cords behind my wall.

Were they supposed to ask, or was I? Is it within my rights to call them up and demand they complete the job?

Comment: I doubt there's any kind of standard of TV mounting. The only way to find out if this particular service includes hiding wires is to call the store and ask. I'm 99% sure that for $250 you just get someone to come and hang the TV for you.  Running wires trough the wall and installing an extra recessed outlet would probably set you back much more

Comment: Did you sign any paperwork (installation contract, work order) and if so, what does it say about what the installers would and would not do?

Comment: Pictures on what cords are exposed. It may not be code to "hide" them in the wall. There would have to be an approved outlet box and the cord that plugs into this does not belong in the wall.

Comment: I think this borders on a legal question about what is typically included in a contract (which would be OT).

Comment: @Niall. - No contract, no work order, no paper work -- besides the receipt for the TV & mount. The installation was separate and cash. Clearly this was a bad move on my part.

Comment: @BMitch - I'm just wondering about convention here. As I said to NiallC., there was no contract.

Comment: My opinion, but "how do I hide this wiring" is on topic, "is hiding the wiring typically included in a contract" is off topic. Side note, cash only without any paperwork from a big name electronics store? Did the big name operate out of the back of a truck starting with an M and rhyming with Bosnia? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on what you paid for.

Best Buy, for example, offers multiple different TV installation packages, [some of which include routing the cables in the walls](http://www.bestbuy.com/site/Geek+Squad®+-+45%22+and+Smaller+TV+Mounting+and+Whole+Room+Setup/3552354.p?id=1218412710124&skuId=3552354), and [others that don't](http://www.bestbuy.com/site/Geek+Squad®+-+Whole+Room+Setup+with+Nonconcealed+Wires/3551364.p?id=1218412701912&skuId=3551364).  Other big box stores presumably structure their installation services similarly.

Check your receipt/agreement and figure out what service you selected.

If you paid for a "hide the cables" plan and didn't get it, you obviously should be complaining and should start complaining right away.